# How to dynamically specify app name on automatic when using gitLab ci/cd

Tags: android, continuous-integration, gitlab

In the Android project that I am working on, we are using GitLab CI/CD to automatically build and upload in Diawi the .apk file. In current settings build application's name is static because it needs to be known and sent to the Diawi framework as a curl request. The script looks like this:

```
- ./gradlew assembleRelease && cp app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk app-release.apk && curl -v --http1.1  https://upload.diawi.com/ -F token=$DIAWI_TOKEN -F file=@app-release.apk -F find_by_udid=0 -F callback_emails="mymail@company.com"
```

But this causes some troubles during the manual testing because the .apk files with the same name can be easily mistaken or overwritten.

My idea is to add some metadata in the .apk file's name to be unique and to avoid such errors. Do you have any ideas about how this could be done?

Comment: Is versioning information what you are looking for? I.e., would something like -F file=@app-release_20.12.1.apk make sense?

Comment: it is a better solution than the current one, but I was wondering if I could add some pre-defined text, like "fix_bug_45" or something like that

Answer (score 1):

First thing you can do is create version bump functionality. You can do it via version bumping tool and git sync.

For version bumping you can use our open source tool - https://github.com/relizaio/versioning . Now, assuming that you sync via a file called apk_version, you first initialize this file with the current version like:

```
docker run --rm relizaio/versioning -s YY.0M.Patch > apk_version
```

Then in your CI context, you can bump it with something like

```
docker run --rm relizaio/versioning -s YY.0M.Patch -v $(cat apk_version) -a bump > apk_version
```

Now, in GitLab CI you need to have a block that resolves this. Note, that you also need to commit apk_version file at the end of the bump.

For inspiration - see this question [How to grant permission for semantic-release to push code to master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65212359/how-to-grant-permission-for-semantic-release-to-push-code-to-master/65265124#65265124) and also our sample CD project on GitLab - https://gitlab.com/taleodor/sample-helm-cd/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml

Also my article here may be helpful (note it's a bit outdated at this point): https://worklifenotes.com/2020/02/27/automatic-version-increments-with-reliza-hub-2-strategies/

Finally, for other things that you can add to version GitLab has a list of pre-defined env variables that you can use in whole or partially as modifiers: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html